# Getting stripe session returns No such checkout.session

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have a custom return page for a paylink of stripe.
It returns the session_id (which I get). But it shows an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught (Status 404) (Request 'some string') No such checkout.session: "session_id" thrown in public_html/wp-content/plugins/yith-stripe-connect-for-woocommerce-premium/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php on line 38.
```

That line is on a plugin used on a different area on the site, but not for this specific page, maybe that is conflicting.

I have checked the dashboard and can see the session_id and that is correct. So I am not sure where it goes wrong.

I use the following code:

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('API key');

$session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->retrieve($_GET['session_id']);
```

and then do something with that session data.

Comment: How are you passing the session ID from your client? Have you logged out the session ID on your Server when retrieving it via `$_GET['session_id']`?

Comment: The session_id is in the url, that is what gets added to the return url when completed, the session_id is nowhere else (accept on the stripe dashboard)

Comment: Right but you are currently using the key of "session_id" instead of the value of "cs_xxx". That is why you are seeing a `No such checkout.session: "session_id"` error and why I recommend logging out the `$_GET['session_id']` so you can see what you are actually passing to `retrieve()`. You can see in the API Ref (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve?lang=php) that this should be the Checkout Session ID string.

Comment: Nope, I do get the session_id, in the url it starts with: ?session_id=cs_live_....... And if I print $_GET['session_id'], I get the session_id from the url